# XOR match in regex

Tags: php, regex

I need to try and match a string which is either a static `@` or matches the pattern `[^\d][\w\.\-]+`.

I know I can use `(...|...)` to do or matches, but I can't seem to get either `@` or `[^\d][\w\.\-]+` to match exclusively.

Here's my current attempt: `(@|[^\d][\w\.\-]+)`

So, in this mean it would do match in the following manner:

```
'@'    MATCH

'www'  MATCH

'@www' NOT MATCH

'www@' NOT MATCH

'w@w'  NOT MATCH
```

Any suggestions?

For the record this is doing a match in PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can live with a whole string match, then add `^` and `$` anchors.

And the `[^\d]` would match **anything** that is not a number. Anything would include `@`. So add an assertion:

```
preg_match('/^(@|(?!@)[^\d][\w\.\-]+)$/', $subject)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to force it to match the whole string with `^...$`
2. The second expression matches `@www` just fine because it's valid according to the rule.  You need to fix your rule with something like `[\d@]`

Demo: http://rubular.com/r/wrXL4yKxq3